# How to use util.promisify to promisify a function in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to convert a Callback function into a Promise,
I'm using util.promisify for this and following is my working code vs the new non working one.

**Working code, using Node Callback style -**

```
let AWS = require(aws-sdk');
let moduleName = process.env.Module;

module.exports = {
    getConstants
};

function getConstants (callback) {
    let client = new AWS.SSM({
        region: "us-east-1"
    });

    let smName = "/somePath";

    let params = {
        Names: [smName]
    };

    client.getParameters(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
            callback(err, null);
        }
        else{
            console.log(METHOD_TAG,'Parameter Store call successful!');
            let constantVariables = data.Parameters[0].Value;
            callback(null, constantVariables);
        }
    });
}
```

**New Non working code -**

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let util = require('util');
let moduleName = process.env.Module;

module.exports.getConstants = async () => {
    let client = new AWS.SSM({
        region: "us-east-1"
    });

    let smName = "/somePath";

    let params = {
        Names: [smName]
    };

    let parameterStore = util.promisify(client.getParameters).bind(client);
    let response = await parameterStore.getParameters(params);
    let constantVariables = response.Parameters[0].Value;
    return constantVariables;
};
```

**I am getting the following error -**

```
TypeError: parameterStore.getParameters is not a function"
```

when trying to promisify the getParameters function of the AWS.SSM client.
What am I doing wrong, what should I change?

**Reference -**
https://medium.com/@suyashmohan/util-promisify-in-node-js-v8-d07ef4ea8c53

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html#getParameters-property

Comment: If you promisify a `getParameters` function and assign it to `parameterStore`, then `parameterStore` would be the promisified version of `getParameters`. It wouldn't have its own `getParameters` property.

Comment: So I need to do await parameterStore(params); ?

Comment: In your linked reference it is `const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile); readFile('./index.js', 'utf8')`. So in your case it has to be `let parameterStore = util.promisify(client.getParameters).bind(client); let response = await parameterStore(params);`

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but this is what the callback code would like like as a promise https://pastebin.com/yrLNxh4v

Comment: Thanks for helping guys, got it working, let response = await parameterStore(params); should have been the correct call.